# Tournament existence

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

> Does a tournament of $n$ teams, each of which plays against exactly $n−2$ opponents exactly once, exist?

My instinct is that it does, because I feel that we can construct some graph with $n$ vertices satisfying the property that it has $n - 2$ edges. At the same time, I cannot exhibit such a construction by brute force, and I was wondering whether I could get any help with this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another alternative:

Schedule a tournament where everyone play against each other exactly once. Gather everyone in a waiting room. Select a pair from inside the waiting room, cancel their match, and let them leave the room. Keep repeating this process and you will have your tournament.

We can see that if $n$ is odd, there will be one remaining participant in the waiting room and you cannot cancel any other match so this participant has to play in $n-1$ match. Therefore, you can only have such tournament if $n$ is even.

Answer (score 3):

It exists iff $n$ is even.

If $n$ is even, then let enumerate teams $1, 2, \ldots, 2k$, and let team $2i - 1$ play with everyone but team $2i$, and team $2i$ with everyone but $2i - 1$.

If $n$ is odd, then we would have graph with $n$ vertices of odd degree $n - 2$, but number of vertices with odd degree should be even.